# Fixed Effects in a model I ANOVA. Why should the parameters sum to zero?

Tags: regression, anova, fixed-effects-model

Let our model be: $X_{ij}=\mu+\alpha_i+\epsilon_{ij}$, with $\epsilon_{ij}\sim^{iid}N(0,\sigma^2)$. The $\alpha_i$ is the fixed-effect, and $i \in \{1,...,m\}$, $j\in \{1,...,n_i\}$.

If we have $m+1$ parameters for $m$ equations, we need one more equation to determine the parameters, but why should we have that $\sum _i n_i\alpha_i=0$, or $\sum _i \alpha_i=0$ if $\forall i \ n_i=n$?

Is it just to make it easier to compute the expected value of the estimator for $\sigma^2$ that uses the sum of squares between groups, when the null is not true? Or would changing this extra condition change many things?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability

Comment: @Glen_b could please explain me how identifiability relates to this question? It could help me understand your comment...

Comment: Compare the opening sentence of the second paragraph at the link with the opening sentence of whuber's comment (which - besides describing the particular kind of non-identifiability here - contains the word "identify" being used in exactly this sense). The link is for additional context for anyone unfamiliar with the notion.

Comment: @Glen_b so what you're saying is that without an extra condition the model would not be identifiable. Thanks for the extra info. ;) Could you also help me with the reason why we should use this precise condition?

Comment: If your model is not identifiable you'll have a set of parameter values that all have the same fit. If the parameters are continuous there will be an infinity of exactly equally-good fits. Consider trying to estimate the parameters of a model like $Y_i\sim(\alpha_1-\alpha_2,\sigma^2)$ from a set of observations $y_i,\,i=1,...,n$. You can estimate the difference $\alpha_1-\alpha_2$ just fine, but you have no hope of telling what the individual parameters are, since $(\alpha_1+\delta)-(\alpha_2+\delta)$ would have the same fit, for any $\delta$.

Comment: whuber already described exactly this issue in terms of your original problem and the link explains the general case. Reread them carefully, because my explanation doesn't really add anything to what they say.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for your effort to explain this to me. Can I ask you if find this question if not interesting, at least well structural and not nonsensical? I'm trying to assess whether I'm understanding what I'm studying by myself or not.

Comment: @whuber I'm sorry to come back to this question after so long, but I forgot about it until recently. I've understand that we need the problem identifiability so that we need m linearly independent equations for identifying m parameters. My question is now, why do we need that exact condition?

Comment: What is the "exact condition" to which you refer?

Comment: @whuber the linear combination of fixed-effects being equal to zero.

Comment: It's arbitrary but convenient.  You are free to impose any set of constraints that will lead to identifiable parameters.  Usually such constraints are chosen to be linear and to have simple, relevant interpretations.  When the $m$ equations are linearly independent, a single linear constraint (that is independent of those) will suffice.  Instead of the sum-to-zero constraint, you could elect to set any single coefficient to zero (thereby making its variable the "baseline"): such constraints are also popular and easy to interpret.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/257778/119261

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you don't apply some such constraint, you could not identify any of the parameters,** because you could add an arbitrary $\delta$ to each $\alpha_i$ and compensate by subtracting $\delta$ from $\mu$.

**You are free to impose any set of constraints that will lead to identifiable parameters.**  The sum-to-zero constraints shown in the question are arbitrary but convenient ways to pin down a particular set of solutions.  Usually such constraints are chosen to be linear and to have simple, relevant interpretations. When the $m$ equations are linearly independent, a single linear constraint (that is independent of those) will suffice. Instead of the sum-to-zero constraint, you could elect to set any single coefficient to zero (thereby making its variable the "baseline"): such constraints are also popular and easy to interpret.